# I want to right justify the TextButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-design

I want to send the "See More" button in the middle to the right.

[image]

```
Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: const <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Your Watchlist',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'See More >>',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 16),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => movie_list(),
                  ));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Also, how can I pull data from firebase to listview items in the form of cards at the bottom, can you suggest a source on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by 2 methods

Option1

Add

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
```

To the row widget

Or

Option2

add

```dart
Spacer()
```

Between the see more and the stack widget

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work either. The spacer() code fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can include `Spacer()` on middle portion,

```
Row
 - WidgetA
 - Spacer()
 - WidgetB
```

Comment: Thanks, as you said I encapsulated it in row() and handled it with spacer() and using extra padding did what I wanted.

Comment: You already have padding on  left and right widget, that's why I ignore that.